# Can't get end value of an IRange in R/Bioconductor

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am new to the IRanges package and am having trouble getting the end value of an IRange.  I am able to get the start and width values with no problem, which has me a bit baffled, and my case/spelling of end match the header line.  Has anyone else run into this or can please spot what I am doing wrong?  Thanks and it is much appreciated!

```
library(IRanges)
> test=IRanges(100645,100664)

> test
IRanges of length 1
 start    end width
[1] 100645 100664    20

> test@start
[1] 100645

> test@width
[1] 20

> test@end
Error: no slot of name "end" for this object of class "IRanges"
```

Comment: In general (and for your future reference), you should consider the slots "private" and shouldn't be accessing their values directly via `@`. If the package developer wants to give you access to something, they will do so via an accessor function, eg. `width(test)`, `start(test)` or `end(test)`, as Lianzinho pointed out

Answer (score 3):

The easiest manner to access the fields of an IRange object is using the helper functions: `start()`,`end()` and `width()`. These will return a vector with all the elements of the corresponding column.

Comment: Thanks!  Very strange that the @ notation worked for two of the three fields, but will now use the helper methods.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @rattlerray that's because the `@end` slot does not exist at all. You can see it by typing `str(IRange_object)`. Just the `@start` and `@width` are defined. Probably the `end` is calculated from them.

Answer (score 1):

No experience with the package, but based on `?"class:Ranges"`:

```
end(test$ranges[1])
```

It would also help in the future to provide reproducible sample data.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I forgot to paste in the line where I actually declared the IRange.  Worked great. Thanks!