# Is it bad practice to access S4 objects slots directly using @?

Tags: r, r-s4

This one is almost a philosophical question: is it bad to access and/or set slots of S4 objects directly using `@`?

I have always been told it was bad practice, and that users should use "accessor" S4 methods, and that developers should provide their users with these. But I'd like to know if anybody knows the real deal behind this?

Here's an example using the `sp` package (but could be generalised for any S4 class):

```
> library(sp)
> foo <- data.frame(x = runif(5), y = runif(5), bar = runif(5))
> coordinates(foo) <- ~x+y
> class(foo)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

> str(foo)
Formal class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 5 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ bar: num [1:5] 0.621 0.273 0.446 0.174 0.278
  ..@ coords.nrs : int [1:2] 1 2
  ..@ coords     : num [1:5, 1:2] 0.885 0.763 0.591 0.709 0.925 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 0.591 0.155 0.925 0.803
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slots
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr NA

> foo@data
        bar
1 0.6213783
2 0.2725903
3 0.4458229
4 0.1743419
5 0.2779656
> foo@data <- data.frame(bar = letters[1:5], baz = runif(5))
> foo@data
  bar        baz
1   a 0.22877446
2   b 0.93206667
3   c 0.28169866
4   d 0.08616213
5   e 0.36713750
```

Comment: In short, the answer to your question is "Yes, it is bad practice." See Martin's answers for a more detailed exposition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general it is good programming practice to separate the content of an object from the interface, see [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding). The idea is to have the interface separate from the implementation, in that way the implementation can change considerably, without affecting any of the code that interfaces with that code, e.g. your script. Therefore, using `@` creates less robust code that is less likely to work in a few years time. For example in the `sp`-package mentioned by @mdsummer the implementation of how polygons are stored might change because of speed or progressing knowledge. Using `@`, your code breaks down, using the interface your code works still. Except ofcourse if the interface also changes. But changes to the implementation are much more likely than interface changes.

Comment: Paul, I think S4 slots are kind of in a gray zone between public and private parts of an object. The official documentation of S4 classes requires you to list the slots and explain them, which is quite public. So I'd be as cautious about changing slots as I'd be about other user-visible changes.

Comment: R S4 classes are also not proper object orientation as I understand, see this thread for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521651/r-and-object-oriented-programming

Comment: I agree: with "proper" object orientation, I'd expect the method to belong to a class, in semi-R-syntax `object@method <- function (...)`. In R, the methods are much more central than in other "proper" object oriented languages. <br/>And IMHO R's FOSS + interactive philosophy hardly distinguishes bewteen users and developers. I guess no-private-slots-in-S4 is one symptom of that.

Answer (score 20):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746637/cant-get-end-value-of-an-irange-in-r-bioconductor) a stackoverflow-er asks why they can't find the `end` slot in a [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) IRanges object; after all there are `start()`, `width()`, and `end()` accessors and `start` and `width` slots. The answer is because the way users interface with the class differs from how it is implemented. In this case, the implementation is driven by the simple observation that it is not space-efficient to store three values (start, end, width) when only two (which two? up to the developer!) are sufficient. Similar but deeper examples of divergence between interface and implementation are present in other S4 objects  and in common S3 instances like the one returned by `lm`, where the data stored in the class is appropriate for subsequent calculation rather than tailored to represent the quantities that a particular user might be most interested in. Nothing good will come if you were to reach in to that `lm` instance and change a value, e.g., the `coefficients` element. This separation of interface from implementation gives the developer a lot of freedom to provide a reasonable and constant user experience, perhaps shared with other similar classes, but to implement (and to change the implementation) classes in ways that makes programming sense.

This doesn't really answer your question, I guess, but the developer is *not expecting* the user to directly access slots and the user should not expect direct slot access to be an appropriate way to interact with the class.

Answer (score 14):

In short, the developer should provide methods for every use case, but in practice this is pretty darn hard and it is complicated to cover every possible use. Technically and as far as I am concerned, if *you need more than the developer provides* and you must use "@" to get at unexposed features, then you *are a developer* (the distinction is happily blurry here in GNU software).

The `sp` package is a good example to ask this question about, since the complications of heirarchical data structures required by "polygons" and "lines" throw up some pretty simple issues. Here is one:

The `coordinates()` method for polygons and lines returns only a centroid for each object, though for points it returns every "coordinate" from the object, but that is because "Points" are "one-to-one". One object, one coordinate, true also for SpatialPoints and SpatialPointsDataFrame. This is not true for Line and Polygon, or Lines and Polygons, or SpatialLines and SpatialPolygons, or SpatialLinesDataFrame and SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. These are composed inherently of >two coordinate line tracks or >three-coordinate poly "rings". How to get the coordinate of every vertex in every Polygon from every multi-branched SpatialPolygon? You cannot unless you delve into the developer structure with "@".

Is it remiss of the developers to not have provided this? No, the advantages very much outweigh the problems any particular user can see in hindsight. In general, the fact that you *can* delve in is a massive bonus but you automatically take on the onus of the developer, and probably make the situation harder if you choose to share your efforts without wrapping it in methods.

Comment: I'd say it is not only impractical to ask the developer to think of every use case: the FOSS philosophy is that this is impossible, but instead the user has the possiblity to contibute the code for *his* unthought-of use case.

Answer (score 13):

As developer of a S4 class, my opinion is:

If you *read* slots with @, you do that at your own risk (like pretty much everything you do in R - see below for some famous examples). That being said, the **slots of an S4 class are actually part of the documented interface**.

The main advantages of access via `@` I see is speed:

```
> microbenchmark (accessor = wl (chondro), direct = chondro@wavelength)
Unit: nanoseconds
      expr    min       lq   median       uq    max
1 accessor 333431 341289.5 346784.5 366737.5 654219
2   direct    165    212.5    395.0    520.0   1440
```

(the accessor function does valitidy checking in addition to returning the `@wavelength` slot which causes the difference. I'd expect every decent public accessor function to ensure validity)

I even recommend using read access to the slots of my class in time-critical situations (e.g. if lots of subsets of the same object are accessed, it may be worth while to skip checking the validity of an unchanged object every time), and in the code of my package I predominantly read the slots directly, ensuring validity at the beginning of functions and at the end of functions where the object could have become invalid. One may argue that the (R) design decision that `@<-` does not check validity does cause an enormous overhead in practice because methods working on S4 objects can not rely on the object being valid and thus even methods with purely read access have to do validity checking.

If you think about *write* access to a slot, you should really know what you are doing. `@<-` does **not** do any validity checking, the official write accessor should do that. And, the write accessor possibly does much more than just update one slot in order to keep the object's state consistent.

So, if you write into a slot, expect to find yourself in hell and do not complain. ;-)

Thinking a bit further along the philosophical line of this: my package is public under GPL. I not only allow you to adapt the code to your need, but I want to encourage you to develop/adapt the code for your needs. Actually it's really easy in R - everything is already there in a normal interactive R session, including access to the slots. Which is quite in a line with design decisions that make R very powerful but allow things like

```
> T <- FALSE
> `+` <- `-`
> pi <- 3
> pi + 2
[1] 1
```

Comment: Presumably your S4 documentation tells the user why you need to do the validation, and a fair 'speed' comparison involves exactly the same validation? If skipping validation is a common use case, shouldn't your accessor allow that, e.g., with an additional flag?

Comment: Martin, `? validObject` tells you that validity is checked automatically when an object is created by `new ()`, and gives an example that this is not the case after `@<-`. So that is documented behaviour.

Comment: @Martin: I'd not call skipping validation a common use case.  However, *the* use case is that the data set is big, i.e. uncomfortably close the available RAM. Thus, you don't want to take the clean way of producing an intermediate object with the contents of the slot (a matrix or data.frame) and subset that one. As it is easier to get more data than to get the forms filled in to buy more RAM, this is not that seldom. So: it happens, but people who want to fill their RAM till the last byte should know what they are doing.

Comment: @Martin, part III: I'd definitively not recommend skipping validation to a user who's not that much on the developer side of the R user spectrum to know how to read the slot directly. I completely agree with the other posts here that `@slot` feels like using `:::.whateverinternalfunction`. But there is the fact that the slots are expected to be documented which I read as a strong hint that they are part of the public interface.

Comment: @Martin, IV: Allowing to switch to "no validation" could be easily and consistently done by checking for some `skipvalidation` option at the beginning of the validity checking - but I too much agree with everyone else in this thread to like the idea. I'm fine if someone decides to skip validation - but then he should use the internal functions I have (for many tasks I have an intermediate internal function that does the actual work, and the exported function wraps all kinds of checking around that). Personally, I take both `@` and `:::` as a reminder of taking a certain additional risk.

Comment: it just doesn't sound like 'speed' is the main advantage here... Subverting developer intentions and knowledge of class structure? But that doesn't sound like an advantage.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX: We say in your post that **slots of an S4 class are actually part of the documented interface.**. Could you point me to the exact reference where this is said?