# How to access the slots of an S4 object in R

Tags: r, r-s4, slots, wavelet

I'm working with wavelets on a program and I'm used the package `wavelets` to create the DWT of a time series using the function `dwt`. This function returns an object of class `dwt`, which is a S4 object with many slots: `W`, `V`, `levels`, `filter`, and so on.

How can I access the `W`'s as a vector?

Comment: how can i find the names of the slots tho?

Comment: @shigeta You can use `slotNames`. Also note that you can visit the [R Public chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public) if you have any clarifications

Answer (score 43):

`@` will let you access the slots of an S4 object.

So if your object is called `wave`, then `wave@W` should get you your vector.

Note that often the best way to do this is to not access the slot directly but rather through an accessor function (e.g. `coefs()` rather than digging out the coefficients with `$` or `@`).  However, often such functions do not exist so you have to access the slots directly.  This will mean that [your code breaks if the internal implementation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900134/is-it-bad-practice-to-access-s4-objects-slots-directly-using), however.

Comment: There is also the function `slot(x,name)`

Answer (score 2):

Ari B. Friedman's answer is good.

But please keep in mind that using `@` to access the slots of an S4 object may not be a good practice. See the discuss here: [Is it bad practice to access S4 objects slots directly using @?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9900134/6088044)