# Extract full p-value from Lavaan CFA output in R

Tags: r, p-value, r-lavaan, factor-analysis

R-novice here. I am running a CFA using the Lavaan package. It is giving me everything I need, except my p-value is coming up at .000 and I would like to find the exact p-value (i.e. .0000009 or whatever it might be).

I have tried to use:

```
format.pval(p, digits=6)
```

and

```
options(digits=10)
```

but neither of these changed my output.

The code I am using is:

```
fit<-cfa(model,data=fulldata,estimator = "WLSMV") 
summary(fit,fit.measures=TRUE,standardized=TRUE)
```

Comment: `fitmeasures(fit)["pvalue"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lavaan has special classes for its output, with dedicated print methods.  The number of digits is controlled by the `nd=` argument (see the `class?lavaan` help page for more details).  For example:

```
example(cfa)
summary(cfa, nd = 5)

PE <- parameterEstimates(fit)
print(PE, nd = 6)

FM <- fitMeasures(fit, "pvalue")
print(FM, nd = 7)
```

Comment: AMAZING! That worked! Thank you so much -- I have literally banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out -- I very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can generally control the number of decimal places displayed using `sprintf()`. Here is an example displaying the first 20 decimal places of `1/7`:

```
sprintf("%.20f", 1/7)
```

In your case, you would replace `1/7` by `p`. Make sure that `p` is a numeric value, not a string. If necessary, coerce (i.e., convert) `p` to numeric using `as.numeric()`. Also note that the output of `sprintf()` will be a string, not a number.

Comment: Thank you for helping -- I am still a bit lost, because I am not sure where in my code to add this. The p-value is stored within the "fit" variable I have created -- so I am not sure at what point I can add in specifiers to modify values that are part of that variable.

Comment: Sorry, I sidestepped lavaan in my earlier post. It seems you can access the p-value from the model like this: `p <- fit@baseline$test$standard$pvalue`. After that, try `sprintf("%.20f", p)`. (20 is just an example for a sufficiently large number of decimal places.) Reaching directly into an S4 object as I just did with `fit` is [not always good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900134/is-it-bad-practice-to-access-s4-objects-slots-directly-using) but it should be fine for reading access, as in your case. `sprintf()` also works (for me) with the `FM` object from Terrence's answer.

Comment: Thank you!! I very much appreciate the follow up!